# Method to square every digit of an int not working

Tags: python, int, square

```
def square_digits(num):
    x = 0
    for i in str(num):
        y = int(i) * int(i)
        x += y 
    return x
```

The above code is supoose to square every digit of an integer and concatenate it  that is passed in but it doesnt do that.
I ran the belpow code and it gives the output 164.

`square_digits(9119)`

Comment: Seems correct though: 9² + 1² + 1² + 9² = 164

Comment: And what do you expect? 81 + 1 + 1 + 81 equals indeed 164.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to output `811181`, you need to change `x` to a string :

```
def square_digits(num):
    x = ''
    for i in str(num):
        y = int(i) * int(i)
        x += str(y) 
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

It's answer is True:
`9*9 + 1*1 + 1*1 + 9*9 = 81 + 1 + 1 + 81 =164`

Comment: i wanted to concatenate the digits